# Django switch from sqlite3 to Postgresql issues

Tags: django, postgresql, import

I've recently changed the database server on my project from sqlite3 to Postgresql and I have a few questions that I hope will give an answer to my issues.

1. I understand that switching from sqlite to Postgres implies that I create the new database and the tables inside it, right? I've done that but I haven't seen any new files created in my project to show me that the database I've made is visible. (Btw, I've changed the database name in settings.py)
2. I probably should mention that I'm working in a virtual environment and I would like to know if that affects my references in any way. I've tried to import the tables in Django to try and count the number of records in a table but I get the error: "No module named psdemo". (psdemo is my database name and i'm trying to import the table with:

   ```
   from ps.psdemo import Product
   ```

   where ps is my application, psdemo is my database and Product the table in the database.

In conclusion I'm trying to get access to my database and tables but I can't manage to find them. I repeat, there is no new database file in my project or in my virtual environment (I've searched thoroughly) but if I use a terminal connection I can connect to my virtual environment and change directories to get to the application folder then if I connect to the Postgresql server I can create the database, the tables and can Insert into them, make queries etc, but I cannot access them from the Django code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that switching from sqlite to Postgres implies that I create the new database and the tables inside it, right? I've done that but I haven't seen any new files created in my project to show me that the database I've made is visible. (Btw, I've changed the database name in settings.py)

All you have to do with postgres is create the database. Not the tables. Django will create the tables, and anything else it thinks are useful, once you call syncdb.

You won't have any new files in your project like you did in sqlite. If you want to view your database, you should download and install pgadminIII (which I would recommend in any event)

> I probably should mention that I'm working in a virtual environment and I would like to know if that affects my references in any way. I've tried to import the tables in Django to try and count the number of records in a table but I get the error: "No module named psdemo". (psdemo is my database name and i'm trying to import the table with:

Here, you import models via normal python syntax and it then references your tables. Each model should represent a single table. You define your models first, and then call

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

> In conclusion I'm trying to get access to my database and tables but I can't manage to find them.

See above, but you should definitely read about postgres installation from the postgres docs, and read the psycopg2 docs as well as the Django docs for setting up a postgres database.

Comment: If I could I would upvote your answer but haters downvote my questions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that switching from sqlite to Postgres implies that I
>   create the new database and the tables inside it, right? I've done
>   that but I haven't seen any new files created in my project to show me
>   that the database I've made is visible. (Btw, I've changed the
>   database name in settings.py)

Database files are not created in the project directory with postgresql. They are created in the database server data directory (like /var/lib/postgres it depends on the distribution). You should generally query it through a PostgreSQL client that connects to the PostgreSQL server rather than messing with the files directly.

You can for example run command:

```
manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: Ok, I've ran the command and it connects me to the server that I used to connect as well. Any other hints on how I can access my data?

Comment: You could do an export with pg_dump command, a restore with pg_restore command, or use manage.py loaddata/dumpdata, or just use some models and django will take care of the rest !

Comment: I have a made a little mistake, and dropped my psdemo database and now it seems I cannot connect to dbshell anymore.

Comment: Create the database again, run syncdb again, and it should be back in order.

Comment: How do I create the database without connecting to the dbshell?

Comment: The first time I created the db, I connected to the shell command and I ran the CREATE DATABASE psdemo command...

Comment: I change my question, how do I create a database accessible only by another user? I can't seem to find the command... I tried createdb psdemo -U x but it didn't work.

Comment: Use createdb -O flag to set the owner of the new database.

Answer (score 0):

As to your first issue, see @jpic's answer.

On your second issue, your database is not a package, and you do not import models from your database. If you were able to import your models correctly before you made any changes, *change your import statements back to how they were.*